# Как проигрывать по очереди массив аудио в Unity?

Tags: c#, массивы, unity3d

У меня есть достаточно большой массив из 60 треков. Мне необходимо, чтобы они играли по очереди. При смене сцены также прерывался трек и играл следующий по очереди. То есть в одной сцене могут сыграть 0,1,2 элемент. После переключения сцены должен играть 3 и т.д.
На просторах интернета нашел функцию, которая вроде бы должна работать так как я и хочу. Но я не совсем понимаю как ее правильно вызвать.

```
public AudioClip[] clipArray;
public AudioSource effectSource;
private int clipIndex;

void PlayRoundRobin() {

if (clipIndex < clipArray.Length)
{
    effectSource.PlayOneShot(clipArray[clipIndex]);
    clipIndex++;
}

else
{
    clipIndex = 0;
    effectSource.PlayOneShot(clipArray[clipIndex]);
    clipIndex++;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй такое решение:

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class MusicPlayer : MonoBehaviour

{
    [SerializeField] private AudioClip[] _audioClips;
       
    private static int _lastAudioIndex = 0;

    private Coroutine _audioPlayCoroutine;
    private AudioSource _audioSource;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (FindObjectsOfType<MusicPlayer>().Length > 1)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }

        _audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        SceneManager.activeSceneChanged += OnActiveSceneChanged;

        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        SceneManager.activeSceneChanged -= OnActiveSceneChanged;
    }

    private void OnActiveSceneChanged(Scene arg0, Scene arg1)
    {
        if (_audioPlayCoroutine != null)
        {
            StopCoroutine(_audioPlayCoroutine);

            _lastAudioIndex++;
        }

        _lastAudioIndex = GetClipIndex();
        _audioPlayCoroutine = StartCoroutine(GetAudioPlay());
    }

    private IEnumerator GetAudioPlay()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var clip = _audioClips[_lastAudioIndex];

            _audioSource.clip = clip;
            _audioSource.Play();

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(clip.length + Time.deltaTime);

            _audioSource.Stop();

            _lastAudioIndex++;
            _lastAudioIndex = GetClipIndex();
        }
    }

    private int GetClipIndex()
    {
        return _lastAudioIndex % _audioClips.Length;
    }
}
```